# Trying to wrap my head around objects, constructors and prototypes

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
function Robot(weapon) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
    this.fire = function() {
        alert('Firing ' + this.weapon + 'projectile.');
    };
}

var gunRobot = new Robot('gun');
```

vs.

```
function makeRobot(weapon) {
    return {
        weapon: weapon,
        fire: function() {
            alert('Firing ' + this.weapon + 'projectile.');
        }
    };
}

var laserRobot = makeRobot('laser');
```

So, if I understood right, the main difference between these two is that in the first example, gunRobot has a constructor property which points to Robot, whereas in the second example, laserRobot has a construtor property which points to Object. Both don't add anything to their prototype, right?

Now, if I change the first example to:

```
function Robot(weapon) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
}

Robot.prototype.fire = function() {
        alert('Firing ' + this.weapon + 'projectile.');
};

var gunRobot = new Robot('gun');
```

gunRobot's constructor property points to the Robot constructor, whose prototype property has a property fire. Now, if I call

```
gunRobot.fire();
```

as, gunRobot doesn not have a fire property, the next prototype up in the prototype chain is visited and checked for a fire property, right?

I'm mainly a Java programmer, so it's quite hard to wrap my head around JS notion of object-orientation :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, really close, but considering this sentence...

> *"gunRobot's constructor property points to the Robot constructor, whose prototype property has a property fire."*

...it seems that you may think that it is via the `constructor` property that `gunRobot` will access its `prototype` object.

That wouldn't be correct. The `gunRobot` object doesn't have a property of its own called `constructor`, but that property is actually a member of the `prototype` object itself.

The way that the `prototype` object is referenced is internal and therefore implicit.

This means...

- You could shadow the `constructor` property on the `gunRobot` object, and still have your implicit reference to the `prototype` object
- You could delete the `constructor` property from the `prototype` object, and the `prototype` chain would be unaffected
- If you entirely replace the `prototype` object of the constructor, any objects that have already been created from the constructor do not see the change. Their `prototype` object reference is permanent. Only new objects would have the internal reference to the new `prototype` object.

---

And with respect to this question...

> *"Both don't add anything to their prototype, right?"*

...you're right that nothing has been added to the `prototype` object of either object. *(Of course, the default `Object.prototype` object has some default properties.)*

---

- `gunRobot` ----> `Robot.prototype` *(empty object)*
- `Robot.prototype` ----> `Object.prototype`
- `Object.prototype` ----> `null`

---

- `laserRobot` ----> `Object.prototype`
- `Object.prototype` ----> `null`